# ASP.NET MVC display property from other model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First of all sorry for that lame naming, but I didn't know how to correctly ask my question.

The point is: I have an ASP.NET MVC application written in C# and I have two model classes - `Song` and `Genre`.

In the `Song` model class, I have a property `GenreId` which points to property `Id` of the `Genre` model class.

In the generated viev for `Song` (which is meant to display song titles with artist and genre names) I have the line with following HTML helper:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GenreId)
```

Which obviously displays the `GenreID`, not the name of the genre.

But how I am suppose to say this HTML helper "display `Genre.Name` which has the same `Genre.Id` as `item.GenreId` ?

I know that to make list of the genres available in view, I have to add the following line:

```
ViewBag.Genres = db.Genres.ToList();
```

In the controller action which returns the view, but how to make it use it that way I described?

Comment: `DisplayFor` is going to use default display template for the type, in this case an integer. One option is to use DropDownListFor and pass your Genres as the items. If you need it to be display only, you can make the input readonly or disabled. If you just want the text you'll need to follow the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC , the most common way to access mulit table is using viewmodel.You may right the model like :

```
    public class SongInfo
    {
        public Song Song {get; set;}
        public Genre Genre {get; set;}
    }
```

Then use linq to select:

```
    var view = from s in db.Song
               join g in db.Genre on s.GenreId equals g.Id
               select new SongInfo
               {
                   Song = s,
                   Genre =g,
               }
```

In the View the helper can be:

```
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre.Name)
```

Comment: But where I'm suppose to declare this **view** variabele? In controller or maybe in the view? In the first case how to pass it to view?

Comment: I finally figuered it out: in the controller action and then pass is as a model to View method. and of course accordingly change the model declaration used in views(and also in helper, like item.Song.Name, instead of just item.Name). In my case also adding new "using" in global.asax.cs, because I add viewmodel in "ViewModels" subfolder of "Models" (so my additional using was like: using [projectname].Models.ViewModels;) - finding this little thing was my major problem, becasue the error I get wasn't very explicit...  
(I think that info may be useful for next people with similar problem.)